# Ruby sorting arrays by grouping and sorting by number

Tags: ruby, sorting

Given an array like

```
['b1','a2','a3','b2','a1','b3']
```

How can i sort it so it groups by letter 'a' or 'b' then sorts these in order of the number present. eg.

```
['a1','a2','a3','b1','b2','b3']
```

or more complicated example:

```
['fb15', 'abc51', 'abc30', 'fb12']
```

which sorts to:

```
['abc30', 'abc51', 'fb12', 'fb15']
```

So hypothetically I could have a large group of different 'tags' like dog. cat, bear, owl. Which all appear in an array a number of times each, each time followed by a number.

Simply I want to group them and then sort by the number.

Comment: Does `Array#sort` not already give you what you need? `['fb15', 'abc51', 'abc30', 'fb12'].sort` produces `["abc30", "abc51", "fb12", "fb15"]`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski not exactly `['abc20','abc1','abc10','abc2'].sort #=> ["abc1", "abc10", "abc2", "abc20"]`

Comment: Another way: `arr.sort_by { |s| i = s.index(/\d/); [s[0,i], s[i..-1].to_i] }`.

Comment: Or anotherway `arr.sort_by {|s| s.split(/(?<=[^0-9])/).tap {|a| a[1] = a[1].to_i }}`

Answer (score 6):

In Ruby, arrays are ordered lexicographically. That means, whenever you have a requirement that you need to order something by a primary, then a secondary, then a tertiary, … ordering key, you can simply convert your item into an array.

```ruby
ary.sort_by do |el|
  str, num = el.partition(/\p{Digit}+/)
  [str, num.to_i]
end
```

Comment: Small issue because of the capture groups `scan` is going to return `[['a','1']]` which means that the destructuring sets `str` to the inner Array and `num` to `nil`.You could go with `str, num = el.partition(/\p{Digit}+/)` instead.

Comment: Thanks. It was working, but only accidentally because `[['abc', 123], nil]` also orders lexicographically because the first element also is examined recursively.

Comment: And we didn't have any numbers like `'10'` and `'2'`, which would be sorted wrong as strings.